# Apache/PHP Segfault can't diagnose with gdb backtrace

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, gdb, fastcgi

I am having troubles figuring out what is causing a Segfault in Apache/PHP.

How do I find out:

**#1)** What script is causing the error??

**#2)** What function does the error occur within??

When I run backtrace, it looks like it is error occurs with init. When I enter into the frames, I'm not seeing any additional information.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002aaab0bc906b in object_properties_init () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#1  0x00002aaab0bc9a8e in _object_and_properties_init () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00002aaab0c3c4e9 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00002aaab0bf6bae in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00002aaab0bf1160 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00002aaab0bf6bae in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#6  0x00002aaab0bb4edf in zend_call_function () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#7  0x00002aaab0bb5d00 in call_user_function_ex () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#8  0x00002aaab0bb5d86 in call_user_function () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#9  0x00002aaab0ac1a5d in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#10 0x00002aaab0ac1cb5 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#11 0x00002aaab0aba753 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#12 0x00002aaab0abae8f in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#13 0x00002aaab0bc6df0 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#14 0x00002aaab0b63c35 in php_request_shutdown () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#15 0x00002aaab0c68cb1 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#16 0x00002b21a22bdf4a in ap_run_handler ()
#17 0x00002b21a22c13d8 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#18 0x00002b21a22cbd3a in ap_internal_redirect ()
#19 0x00002aaaaf707c70 in ap_make_dirstr_parent () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
#20 0x00002b21a22bdf4a in ap_run_handler ()
#21 0x00002b21a22c13d8 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#22 0x00002b21a22cbee8 in ap_process_request ()
#23 0x00002b21a22c90d0 in ?? ()
#24 0x00002b21a22c51d2 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#25 0x00002b21a22d0389 in ?? ()
#26 0x00002b21a22d061a in ?? ()
#27 0x00002b21a22d0e7d in ap_mpm_run ()
#28 0x00002b21a22ab058 in main ()


(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x00002aaab0bc906b in object_properties_init () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so

(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x00002aaab0bf6bae in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so

(gdb) frame 15
#15 0x00002aaab0c68cb1 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

Comment: It is most likely an add-on module. Do you know what modules you are using (e.g. Oracle module, GD module)

Comment: @kainaw what type of module? php or apache?

Comment: Php module. Example... I installed the wrong version of an Oracle module once and got segmentation faults.

Answer (score 1):

> ## 1) What script is causing the error??

There is not enough information in the stack trace to tell you.

You need to install debug symbols for `libphp5.so`, and possibly also for Apache as well. *Then* you may be able to find out the script.

Precise details of how to install debug symbols depend on the OS and distribution you are using, and you didn't tell us about either. Usually it's something like `apt-get install php5-dbg`, `yum install php5-debug` or something like that.

> ## 2) What function does the error occur within??

The error occurs in `object_properties_init()`.